# Leak with HttpRequest Method - Objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, httprequest

I was `Analyze` my app for searching any leak, and here we are with a "Potential leak of an object stored into `replyString`".
I tried every release than I could, but nothing change, so I'm here asking for some help.

I make this method in my WebService Class.

```
-(NSString *)httpRequest{

NSData *postData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adresse]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *replyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
return replyString;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the `replyString` with `alloc` `init` which means `replyString` needs to be released, therefore:

```
return [replyString autorelease];
```

Comment: I tried this before and my app crashed but it seems to be working now, thanks !